# Repeat selected option to all select with exception

Tags: jquery

I have a little JS function allowing me to repeat the first `select` and `input` values if clicked.

It's working very well.

The only problem I'm facing now it if the select do not have the same `option` than the first copied `select`.

Case:
Chose the 'Spécial étudiant' in the top first select and click on the 'Repeat for the whole stay' link. The last select is now blank whereas I would like it 'Custom price' (the first value found).

How can I make it possible please?

https://jsfiddle.net/dq6pwj5L/1/

```
$('#repeatRate').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var price = $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"] option:selected').first().val();
    var rate = $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').first().val();

    $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"]').val(price);

    if(price==0) {
        $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val(rate).prop('readonly', false);
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val(rate).prop('readonly', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check whether an `option` with that value actually exists. The code below does that, albeit a bit messy:

```js
$('#repeatRate').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var price = $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"] option:selected').first().val();
  var rate = $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').first().val();

  $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"]').each(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    if ($select.find("option[value='" + price + "']").length > 0) {
      $select.val(price);
    } else {
      $select
      .val(0) // or whatever else you use as default value
      .parents('tr')
      .find('input')
      .focus();    
    }
  });

  if (price == 0) {
    $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val(rate).prop('readonly', false);
  } else {
    // this line is conflicting with manually setting the focus
    // $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val(rate).prop('readonly', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Date</th>
      <th width="40%">Price of the night $</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Samedi 15 Avril 2017
        <br>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0" data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom price</option>
          <option value="3" data-name="Spécial étudiant" data-description="Spécial étudiant" data-rate="99.99">Spécial étudiant - $ 99.99</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
            <a href="#" id="repeatRate"><small>Repeat for the whole stay</small></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Dimanche 16 Avril 2017
        <br>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0" data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom price</option>
          <option value="3" data-name="Spécial étudiant" data-description="Spécial étudiant" data-rate="99.99">Spécial étudiant - $ 99.99</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">

          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Lundi 17 Avril 2017
        <br>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0" data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Custom price</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">

          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But how I can change remove the price form the next input cause actually the `99.99` is here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what should happen? Perhaps provide a sketch in your post. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to select the next input right after a select which has the 'Custom price'.

Comment: I modified my answer. Please note the commented line in the original code, this messes with setting focus manually. Also, my solution is rather dependant on the structure of the markup; it might be beneficial to set up a mapping of `select`s to their `input`s, e.g. with `data`-attributes, or a more programmatic mapping.